# Add new row to table using jQuery on enter key button

Tags: jquery, html

I need to add a new to the HTML when the user enters something in the "Other" text box.

I'm using the below HTML, JavaScript and CSS code

HTML:

```
<table>
    <tr class="table-header">
        <td class ="table-cell">Game</td>
        <td class ="table-cell">Yes </td>
        <td class ="table-cell">No</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="table-row">
        <td class ="table-cell">
        FootBall
        </td>
        <td class ="table-cell">
        <input type="radio" name="yes">
        </td>
        <td class ="table-cell">
        <input type="radio" name="yes">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="table-row">
        <td class ="table-cell">
        Hockey
        </td>
        <td class ="table-cell">
        <input type="radio" name="yes">
        </td>
        <td class ="table-cell">
        <input type="radio" name="yes">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="table-row">
        <td class ="table-cell">
        Other
        </td>
        <td class ="table-cell">
        <input type="text" name="yes">
        </td>

    </tr>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
.table-header{
    background-color:green;
}
.table-cell{

    width:100px;
    height:20px;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
$(".table-cell-text").keyup(function(event){
    if(event.keyCode == 13){
        //what do I put in here to add a new row?
    }
});
```

When a user presses something under "Other", I need add the new item..For example: If the user enters "Cricket" a new row with cricket needs to be added and OTHER should be removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(".table-cell-text").keyup(function (event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 13) {
        $(this).closest('tr').replaceWith('<tr class="table-row">'+
            '<td class="table-cell">' + this.value + '</td>' +
            '<td class="table-cell">' +
            '<input type="radio" name="yes" />' +
            '</td>' +
            '<td class="table-cell">' +
            '<input type="radio" name="yes" />' +
            '</td></tr>');
    }
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/tZa5z/)

Answer (score 0):

Use `last()` and `after()` to append a new row after the last one:

```
var new_cell_name = $('#your_other_input_field').val();
$('.table-row').last().after('<tr class="table_row">'
    + '<td class="table-cell">' + new_cell_name + '</td>'
    + '<td class="table-cell"><input type="text" name="yes"></td>'
    + '</tr>');
```

**Notes:** you should change the names of your text boxes to either a unique name or use an array like `name="yes[]"` to avoid naming conflicts.

> EDIT

Just noticed you want to **remove** the other row and add the new one, so use `replaceWith()` instead:

```
$('.table-row').last().replaceWith('
```

**Docs:**

- http://api.jquery.com/after/
- http://api.jquery.com/last/
- http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/

Answer (score 0):

You can add a row like this:

```
$('#myTable tr:last').after('<tr>...</tr><tr>...</tr>');
```

You can check if the textbox contains text or is empty with:

```
var inp = $("#txt");
// where #txt is the id of the textbox

if (inp.val().length > 0) {
    // do something
}
```

You can detect `enter` press on keyboard with:

```
$(".table-cell-text").keyup(function (event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 13) {
          alert('You pressed enter');
    }

});
```

Combining these, you get something like this:

### jQuery

```
var inp = $("#txt");
// where #txt is the id of the textbox

$(".table-cell-text").keyup(function (event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 13) {
        if (inp.val().length > 0) {
          $('#myTable tr:last').before('<tr class="table-row"><td class="table-cell">' + inp.val() + '</td>' +
            '<td class="table-cell">' +
            '<input type="radio" name="yes" />' +
            '</td>' +
            '<td class="table-cell">' +
            '<input type="radio" name="yes" />' +
            '</td></tr>');
        }
    }

});
```

Where you change `<table>` in your HTML to e.g. `<table id="myTable">`

### HTML

```
<table id="myTable">
    <tr class="table-header">
        <td class="table-cell">Game</td>
        <td class="table-cell">Yes </td>
        <td class="table-cell">No</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="table-row">
        <td class="table-cell">
        FootBall
        </td>
        <td class="table-cell">
        <input type="radio" name="yes">
        </td>
        <td class="table-cell">
        <input type="radio" name="yes">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="table-row">
        <td class="table-cell">
        Hockey
        </td>
        <td class="table-cell">
        <input type="radio" name="yes">
        </td>
        <td class="table-cell">
        <input type="radio" name="yes">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="table-row">
        <td class="table-cell">
        Other
        </td>
        <td class="table-cell-text">
        <input type="text" name="yes" id="txt">
        </td>

    </tr>
</table>
```

I didn't run the code yet, so beware of any typos.
Hope that helps you out.

You can find a `jsFiddle` [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/ec33E/).

If you want the 'other' `tr` to disappear, you can use `.replaceWith()` instead of `.before()`

Comment: I tried based on your comments on the "enter" but it doesn't work...Here is my fiddle---http://jsfiddle.net/pYAx8/2/

Comment: @user1050619: You didn't incorporate my code. Hang on, I will add my code to your fiddle.

Comment: @user1050619: I changed the fiddle.